# QFTs with a finite cutoff

Tags: quantum-field-theory, string-theory, quantum-gravity, regularization

I'm wondering what exactly happens if a QFT is regularized with a smooth cutoff, but it is **not** sent to infinity at the end of the day. I'm certainly thinking about string theory's exponential smoothness around the string scale.

Polchinski says in his introduction to String Theroy vol. 1

> In quantum field theory it is not easy to smear out interactions in a way that preserves the consistency of the theory. We know that Lorentz invariance holds to very good approximation, and this means that if we spread the interaction in space we spread it in time as well, with consequent loss of causality or unitarity.

The first thing that came to my mind was the Ostrogradski instability, but the theorem applies to a finite number of higher derivatives. A smooth cutoff however needs an infinite number of them. Another possible issue that I thought of is that the cutoff is normally enforced in Euclidean signature. But this affects loop momenta only, which are being integrated over.

I also found this [blog post (paragraph about discretized theories)](https://golem.ph.utexas.edu/%7Edistler/blog/archives/000639.html) by Jacques Distler saying only that it requires fine-tuning due the cosmological constant.

So how exactly does a smooth finite cutoff violates unitarity?

*EDIT*: Today the following paper https://arxiv.org/abs/2111.03672 appeared analysing the non-local field theory effective action of the open string tachyon. As far as I can tell they do not discuss unitarity directly but show that by a field redefinition the theory is local in time and non-local in space only. This implies causality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One cheap way to see this maybe (as in: mathematical, but that doesn't connect immediately to Polchinki) is that a smooth cut-off in momentum space will necessarily alter the analytic structure of the answer and it's hard to see how this would not affect immediately the unitarity cuts. For instance, add a $\exp(-\ell^2 \alpha')$ to a scalar box integral, where $\ell$ is the loop momentum (one-loop) and $\alpha'$ some inverse mass scale. This shuts off high energy modes smoothly, but it stays in any unitarity cut as the exponential of some on-shell momenta and is not a function you expect from a tree-level graph in your theory, at least not if it's just conventional field theory with finitely many particles. Unitarity tells you that at tree-level you might have only poles. This exponential has a bad divergence at infinity on the complex plane. I'm not sure how this relates directly to Polchinski's "wrapping in time" argument though.

Also, note that in string theory, the exponential smoothness of the amplitudes is not a loop effect, it's the result of delicate cancellations between the infinite tower of states. These guys http://arxiv.org/abs/1607.04253 proved that it's universal to any theory of weakly interacting higher spin particles. In string theory, even at loop-level, you don't have a sharp cut-off in momentum space, it is in Schwinger proper-time space that the integration is truncated (as is explained somewhere in Polchinski).

Comment: I implicitly assumed that the cutoff function is part of the propagator, i.e. the theory is regularized already at the level of the (Wick rotated) Lagrangian. So, it should show up in tree-level diagrams, right? However, the bad divergence you mentioned prevents constructing unitarity cuts altogether, if I understand section 7.3 of Peskin/Schroeder correctly. What happens if the exponential is replaced by a more tame function on the complex plane, at the risk of introducing additional zeros and/or poles?

Comment: The paper looks deep, but I need more time to digest it. Thanks! About loops: When performing the sewing construction (Polchinksi chapter 9.4) to reduce the genus 1 closed bosonic string amplitude to a genus 0 amplitude, I got (after a sketchy calculation) a factor of $4^{-\alpha' \ell^2}$ for the tachyon propagator from the integration over the moduli. The momentum cutoff translates to a truncation of the Schwinger proper time. This is actually how I started to think about QFTs with a finite cutoff. It would be interesting to see the connection to the infinite tower of states you mentioned.

Comment: @and008 hmm I'm not sure that this is a factor that you would get from that computation. You might have things like $\exp(\alpha' \tau (\ell^2-4/\alpha'))$ where $\tau$ has the usual UV cutoff at the lower side of the fundamental domain, but it's not really in connection with the loop-momentum part. Concerning your first comment, I'm not sure what to say. If the analytic structure at tree-level is not the one correpsonding to unitarity, you're in trouble... If you insert another function with a heaviside step for instance, you'll change the analytic structure of your answer and that's also bad

Comment: Would you mind to share your thoughts on how you obtained that factor? Regarding "If the analytic structure at tree-level is not the one correpsonding to unitarity", you're referring to the paper you mentioned, right?  I found this paper https://arxiv.org/abs/1803.08827 . They claim to have solved the issue by smearing out the interaction terms.

Comment: @and008 ah ok sorry if the theory is non-local then yes things may happen. Not much is known. For the term you mention, you need to take a one-loop string theory amplitude within the "chiral-splitting" formalism, of D'Hoker and Phong, which is just a way to introduce explicitly loop-momentum. See their 80's review "The geometry of string perturbation theory", e.g. eq. 2.99. Then you need to loop at the $1/(q \bar q)$ of your integrand, which signals the propagation of the tachyon (massless terms have $|q|^0$, etc).

Comment: Regarding the factor, I agree, but isn't it necessary to integrate over the moduli (or at least $\tau_1$) to read off how a QFT calculation would have obtained the same result? This is how I got the exponential cutoff of the propagator.

Comment: @and008 integrating over tau1 (where you can do it, i.e. for |tau_2|>1) gives you the level matching condition, it just projects out states with different number of oscillators in both channels

Comment: You were right, in doing a more thorough calculation, I got for the tachyon partition function (in the $\alpha' \rightarrow 0$ limit) $Z=-\int d^Dp \Gamma(0,p^2+m^2)$, where $m^2=-4/\alpha'$. Interestingly, this corresponds exactly to the Lagrangian $(1)$ and $(8)$ in 1803.08827 (up to constants). But they didn't write where they got it from.

Comment: Apparently I asked the question at the right time. This paper appeared the day after I asked the question: https://arxiv.org/abs/2103.00353 . The same authors show that smearing out interaction terms indeed doesn't make sense in Minkowski signature (perturbatively), only in Euclidean signature and analytically continuing afterwards.

Comment: @and008 thanks for the paper I had missed it !

Comment: There are a few points I would like to clarify. First, the exponential is necessary for the UV finiteness of string theory, not only that there is an infinite tower of massive higher-spin states. Part of the contribution to the exponential comes from "adding stubs", which can also be done for point-particle QFT, even at tree-level (2108.04312 + work in progress). It is possible to define a generalized Wick rotation (1604.01783) and to show that analyticity properties are not modified (1810.07197). See also 1703.06410 and [my book](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-030-65321-7).

Comment: Also note that 1803.08827 came after 1604.01783, 1607.08244, and 1805.00984 which already proved Cutkosky rules and unitarity for non-local models. Concerning 2103.00353, note that they are not considering the same functions in Euclidean and Lorentzian signatures: ine one case they have $H(- \square)$, in the second $H(- \square^2)$. Anyway, it is a fact that QFT in pure Lorentzian signature does not make sense, a proper definition must involve an $i \epsilon$ prescription equivalent to a Wick rotation from Euclidean signature (1604.01783, 1610.00443).

Comment: @Harold Thanks for your comments! I mentioned 1803.08827 since they look at general nonlocal QFTs, not only string-inspired ones. So unitarity and Euclidean loop momenta does not seem to be a problem for general nonlocal-QFTs, right? But what about causality? In general this seems to be violated, see e.g. the discussion in this PhD-Thesis https://research.rug.nl/nl/publications/nonlocal-field-theories-theoretical-and-phenomenological-aspects .

Comment: But the construction in your paper 2111.03672 suggests that the model you considered is indeed causal. Have you tried to find some obstructions to your construction? These could constrain the space of possible effective actions, right? Another question: Does the very existence of the Hamilton for the redefined field imply the existence of an Hamilton of the original field (possibly for *some* momentum and *some* symplectic form)?

Comment: Pius-Sen did look at general models, not only string-inspired: if you look at section 2, the form of the vertices is not specified and can be anything non-local. The restriction is made only in section 6.2. Also for a scalar QFT, Cutkosky rules imply unitarity, so there is not much more to do.

Comment: Causality is really a tricky topic. We continue to investigate this, but to our knowledge no one has given completely convincing argument in one direction or the other (even what we did is not the end of the story) and many people contradict each other so it's quite fuzzy.

Our approach seems to work for generic non-local models and we did not find obvious obstructions. Similarly the discussion of superluminality extends to general delocalized QFT. One puzzle is if one considers a finite number of higher-derivatives: the theory is sick but our algorithm does not have any problem.

Comment: You see, even things like micro-causality are not really understood: e.g. we did not find any explicit example of how it works for an interacting theory, even local, and several proofs look so general that it's hard to see how they can fail, even for non-local theories. For the Hamiltonian, I don't know what to expect. Naively I would say no, that you need to find some time-block Hamiltonian (like in 1507.00981) but maybe there is a map (one way to investigate the relation would be through homotopy transfer).

Comment: And yes causality can be used to put constraints on EFT, which is interesting but I am not familiar with the details (de Rham, Tolley et al. have regularly papers on this).

Comment: @Harold Regarding Pius-Sen: you're absolutely right, I should have read at it better. De Rham, Tolley, et al. haven't considered yet non-local QFTs, afaik. Regarding your algorithm with a finite number of higher derivatives: I started to look at an example, and the coefficients seem to blow up. So I guess either it doesn't converge and (after resumming)/or the resulting potential is not bounded from below. It looks interesting :)

Comment: In total, it doesn't look like to me that general non-local QFTs are so ill-defined as Polchinski stated. Am I wrong?

Comment: @and008 : thanks for the update! This is something we wanted to check at some point, it's good to know.
And indeed it from these papers + others on analyticty (1810.07197, 2009.03375,     2110.13215), it looks like non-local theory and especially SFT are not as badly behaved as naively thought. Polchinski's sentence is quite right about the origin of the problems: what our paper + hep-th/0406199  show is that "good" non-locality can be recast in some gauge / variable as local in some time, but non-local in space.

Comment: @Harold : Thanks for your patience clarifying all these issues! And since we are at it, I have two more questions :) First, what is the role of the infinite tower of higher-spin states? They don't seem to be necessary for unitarity/causality? Second, I know that field redefinitions don't change S-matrix elements, but what about other potential observables? E.g. can your "quasi-symmetries" lead to different theories? The cosmological constant (zero-point function) is not invariant under redefinitions, but it is an observable in theories with gravity, right?

Comment: @Harold guys, I get a notification every single time... can you maybe direct message or e-mail ? Also Harold you might want to post all this in an answer, or maybe and008 ask a new question or something ? Not that it's not nice to read you though. Sincerly yours.

Comment: @picop : sure, let me answer that last one, and then I will make a summary (or @and008) can open a question and ping me (and I am answering emails, in case; just very busy for the next month).
My understanding of SFT is that this tower of states is not necessary, but I would need to study more for being sure.
Field redefinitions should leave all observables invariant (you can show it nicely in the BV formalism I think). I am surprised for what you say for the cosmological constant, I would have expected that the full quantum vacuum amplitude to be invariant.